# Object of class AppBundle\Entity\User could not be converted to string Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form with EntityType but is not running.

This is my BD:

[image]

I already got Users and AcademiucProgram, so I want to create a register between User and AcameicProgram.

From my controller it provides a variable to my form which contains the ID of the user.

My controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request,$id){
    $ac = new Usersacademi();
    $form = $this->createForm(UsersacademiType::class,$ac,array('id'=>$id));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $ac->setIdacademicprogram($form->get("idacademicprogram")->getData());
        $ac->setIduser($form->get("iduser")->getData());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ac);
        $flush = $em->flush();
    }
    else{
    }


    return $this->render("AppBundle:admin:apteacher.html.twig", array(
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
            "required"=>"required",
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))
        ->add('iduser', EntityType::class, array("required"=>"required",
            "data" =>$options["id"],
            'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
            "attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-iduser form-control"
        )))
        ->add('Registrar',SubmitType::class, array("attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-submit btn btn-success"
        )));
}
```

So I want to be able to select the AcademicProgram with a Select Option (this is actually running) and then on the second field (idUser) I want that by default is the id of the user selected (that id number is provided by the controller) and then be able to submit this register.

Comment: On __what__ line of code this error happens?

Comment: Without the full error message it is difficult, but the "could not be converted to a string" means you are trying to pass an object when Symfony is expecting a string. I would guess that $options["id"] is being set to an object instead of the id.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to add `choice_label` in your user form field or you can add a __toString() method inside your User entity.

From the docs:

> If left blank, the entity object will be cast to a string and so must have a `__toString()` method.

By default EntityType already uses entity `id` as value.